# How to convert array from MongoDB to String in HTML?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, jinja2

In each of my collection entry, they have an array of Authors (in String format). I would like to present the authors as Strings in my HTML render of the page.

`<p style="color: white">Authors: {{i['authors']}}</p>`
This is what I currently have, but it appears as:
`Authors: ['Bernerd Allmon', 'Jeremy Anderson']` I would like it to appear as:
`Authors: Bernerd Allmon, Jeremy Anderson` instead.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a screenshot of your code? So we can understand your code better.

Answer (score 0):

if its list you can go as like:

```
 lst= ['Bernerd Allmon', 'Jeremy Anderson']
 author_data=",".join(lst))
```

it will be printed as

```
 print(author_data)
 Bernerd Allmon, Jeremy Anderson
```

and you can pass on data